# How do I brighten the colors in the rxvt family of terminals?

Tags: terminal, colors, rxvt

I know how to lighten the colors for certain commands, however I'd like to lighten the standard ansi colors across all commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found instructions for doing it for Xterm and aterm here:

http://gentoo-wiki.com/TIP_Linux_Colors_in_Aterm/rxvt

From those I was able to get brighter colors by adding:

```
rxvt*background:  #000000
rxvt*foreground:  #7f7f7f
rxvt*color0:      #000000
rxvt*color1:      #9e1828
rxvt*color2:      #aece92
rxvt*color3:      #968a38
rxvt*color4:      #414171
rxvt*color5:      #963c59
rxvt*color6:      #418179
rxvt*color7:      #bebebe
rxvt*color8:      #666666
rxvt*color9:      #cf6171
rxvt*color10:     #c5f779
rxvt*color11:     #fff796
rxvt*color12:     #4186be
rxvt*color13:     #cf9ebe
rxvt*color14:     #71bebe
rxvt*color15:     #ffffff
```

to the bottom of my `~/.Xdefaults` file

Comment: The pointed article does not exist in the current incarnation of gentoo-wiki. But [there is a copy in their archive](http://gentoo-wiki.info/TIP_Linux_Colors_in_Aterm/rxvt). (I'd edit the answer to update the link myself, but, sadly, there's that 6 chars limit...)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to turn up your monitor brightness :)

More seriously, see the RESOURCES section of the [manual](http://seth.positivism.org/man.cgi/rxvt).